# Windows: made 2nd partition, installed Windows, now can't access original partition OS

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

I used Paragon to create a 2nd partition of about 45gb, and then installed an instance of Windows 10 on it from USB. I definitely selected the new partiton and the install went fine.

However, there is now no option at boot, or at the bios, to access the original C: Windows. I can access all the files from the new Windows installation, but I wanted this to be a second dualboot option and not my primary.

Any idea how I can make my original partition back as the primary partition?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the old Legacy boot screen after bios post where you can select which os in W10 open an elevated cmd prompt and use this command (without quotes) "bcdedit /set "{current}" bootmenupolicy legacy"

Comment: @Moab Doesn't seem to work for me sadly. Upon boot it just loads the default, despite that command applying correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Start` > `Run` > `MSCONFIG` and press enter. On the 2nd tab `Boot` select the other partition.

[image]